# how to get argument value from navigator_bar.php?type=1?

Tags: php

I have a below like index.php:

index.php:

```
include_once('navigator_bar.php'); 
include_once('content.php');
include_once('footer.php');
```

my navigator_bar.php just list different product type from database, I loop it from DB and echo they as a link like:

```
navigator_bar.php?type=1
navigator_bar.php?type=2
navigator_bar.php?type=3
...
```

my content.php just show different product list from `navigator_bar.php` retrieve from DB, that's, when user click type one `button(navigator_bar.php?type=1)`, then `content.php` show `type=1` products; when user click type two `button(navigator_bar.php?type=2)`, then `content.php` show `type=2` products.

now my question is : I can't get the parameter "type" value from the `content.php`, because both `navigator_bar.php` and `content.php` are all included in `index.php`, they are all in the same page, can't get it via `"$_GET['type']`,

and they are all contained in div not in frame, still not in form, so I can't get they from a form submit; of course, I can define "type" as a variable in `navigator_bar.php`, get it from `content.php`,

but please note that, my type value loop from database, it's scope just in `navigator_bar.php`, when get it from `content.php`, I can just get the last value of it.

but `my content.php` need to refresh different products from the argument value like `navigator_bar.php?type=value`, anyone have good suggestions for how to get the argument value from the `include navigator_bar.php ?`

regards & thanks
David

Comment: How do you want to get that type argument when the type has not been selected yet? It doesn't make sense if you say you're not using frames

Comment: Hi onetrickpony, thanks for your reply. when the type has not been select, I will give the content.php to show the default type(type=1), any other good solutions except frames ?

Answer (score 0):

Try set a `$_SESSION['type']` in "navigator_bar.php" with the value of type (where you can get that value), then get and use it from session in the other php file.

Both files must have this code at beginning:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
```

Comment: Hi CoursesWeb, thanks for your reply, will try your suggests, thank u very much.